# Script para achar e substituir palavras em múltiplos arquivos

Tags: unix, script

Eu preciso fazer um comando que ache e substitua um caminho de diretório por outro caminho, em vários arquivos HTML, exemplo de parte do arquivo HTML:

```html
<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;" >< FONT ID="f16" >
<A HREF="file:/export100/DOCS_AB/export200/ab.c" >
file:/export100/DOCS_AB/export200/ab.c</A></FONT></DIV>

<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;" >< FONT ID="f16">
<A HREF="file:/export100/DOCS_CD/export200/cd.c">
file:/export100/DOCS_CD/export200/cd.c</A></FONT></DIV>
```

Os nomes dos diretórios mudam assim como os fontes `.C`, eu tentei com os comandos `find` e `sed` assim:

```
find ./ -name *.html | xargs sed -i 's_/export_/media/pendrive_g'
```

O problema é que os diretórios e os fontes sempre mudam o nome.

Gostaria que o comando me retornasse isto:

```html
<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;"><FONT ID="f16">
<A HREF="file:/media/pendrive/"nome_arquivo".c">
file:/media/pendrive/"nome_arquivo".c</A></FONT></DIV>
```

Comment: A tag `<FONT></FONT>` caiu em desuso faz um bom tempo. pode incluir isso no atributo `style` da `div`.

Comment: Uma ideia inicial para fazer isso funcionar, mas que é extremamente ruim para ser uma solução final, seria pegar o caminho direto ao arquivo.

Uma outra ideia seria o uso de softlinks.

Comment: O problema é que eu não posso modificar o arquivo html, a unica coisa que eu posso e quero fazer é mudar os nomes dos diretórios para apontarem para o pendrive.

Comment: script eu não conheço mais tem um programinha que vc faz isso de forma muito rápida e fácil . Você so tera o trabalho de baixar e upar segue o link de download do TEXTREP [Download TEXTREP](http://no-nonsense-software.com/download.shtml)

Answer (score 4):

```
find ./* -name *.* | xargs sed -i 's_/export_/media/pendrive_g'
```

Porque não fazer desta maneira? vai pegar todos os arquivos que tenha algum tipo de extensão. Outra forma é usar `||`  para ele procurar uma situação valida e se encontrar ele executa o código.

```
find ./* -name *.html | xargs sed -i 's_/export_/media/pendrive_g' || find ./* -name *.c | xargs sed -i 's_/export_/media/pendrive_g'
```

No comando find tem a opção  `-maxdepth` e `-mindepth` que define o nível máximo e minimo de diretórios a serem pesquisados como também a função `-regex` para incluir uma expressão regular a ser procurada, alias esta opção pode ser usada para substituir o `||` que usei acima.

Não sei se ajudei, mas pelo que entendi era algo do tipo que você queria.

Answer (score 1):

### Sed

```
sed -i 's#export\([A-Za-z0-9/-\_]*\)/#media/pendrive/#g' *.html
```

A [expressão regular](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) `A-Za-z0-9/-\_` vai corresponder a letras e dígitos, incluindo os caracteres como a [barra](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barra_%28caractere%29) e [traço inferior](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore). Certifique-se de estar na pasta correta, o comando acima vai buscar por arquivos `.html` na pasta atual de trabalho.

Vale lembrar que o comando acima aplica-se ao **GNU** [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), poderá não funcionar do modo esperado caso você esteja usando o **FreeBSD** por exemplo.-

---

### Perl

```
perl -i -p -e 's#export([\w-\/]+)\/#media\/pendrive/#g;' *.html
```